Get resultant wind speed from U and V components in a netcdf file for all latitude, longitdue and times
I have a series of (about 200) netcdf files that have the u and v components of wind speed on a grid of lats and lons for each hour in a month. I am trying to create a colour map of the averge and maximum wind speeds in this period accross the area.
I want to create an xarray with the resultant wind speed, which I calculate as;
math.sqrt(U[i] ** 2 + V[i] ** 2)
for each grid point and the entire time period but I currently cant find a way to combine the u and v components individually then add them to a new xarray.
I have tried the following;
def Wind(U, V):
    W = []
    for i in range(len(U)):
        W.append(math.sqrt(U[i] ** 2 + V[i] ** 2))
    return W

era5_variable = list()
    for i in YEAR:
        for j in range(len(MONTH)):
            filename = os.path.join(directory, "era5_" + i + "_" + MONTH[j] + ".nc")
            f = nc.Dataset(filename)
            u = f["u10"]
            v = f["v10"]
            era5_variable.append(np.mean(Wind(u, v)))

But i get the error: "TypeError: Only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Have a look at ncap2 utility, e.g. https://sourceforge.net/p/nco/discussion/9830/thread/4bb9679e/

You don't need the Wind() function. xarray (netcdf) data has already ndarrays. Also, you have some xarray functions that allows you to perform some of this operations.
I will recomend you:

Numpy

You will need to change the last 3 lines of your code with:
import numpy as np
era5_variable.append(np.mean(np.sqrt(f["u10"]**2 + f["v10"]**2)))

